# Как сделать самый простой слайдер на js или jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать самый простой слайдер на js или jquery?
есть несколько картинок,чтобы они сменяли друг друга через какое то определенное время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаёте div, по размерам равный одной картинке. Задаёте ему свойство overflow: hidden. Внутри него помещаете блок с картинками (картинок столько, сколько нужно). Задаёте этому внутреннему блоку свойство margin-left: -ширина_одной_картинки. Далее через setTimeout или setInterval запускаете функцию, которая сначала будет изменять margin-left до нуля (через JQuery.Aminate, например), а потом одновременно переносить самую правую картинку в начало и задавать заново margin-left: -ширина_одной_картинки.

Comment: есть пример?

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, отличный пример скинул @Heidel, посмотрите первую ссылку

Answer (score 1):

На вкус и цвет - http://yeap.narod.ru/js/022.html

Answer (score 1):

Одна из самых простых каруселей
http://coolcodez.net/create-infinite-carousel-in-jquery-using-a-few-lines-of-code/

Более сложная
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/index.html%3Fp=128.html

Еще
http://realtuts.com/infinite-carousel-with-auto-scrolling-jquery/